# React.js: layout different areas without adding multiple components

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

[image]

Hi, I am currently a beginner to React.js, and I want to know if I could divide the a page's body with different background color without adding multiple components.
I have implemented the header and the footer, but I do not have any ideas to divide a body area into three parts. For example,

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <AreaOne/>
      <AreaTwo/>
      <AreaThree/> 
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I was thinking about to use this kind of method, but I think it might be a better / more commonly used method. Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: Sure. React is pretty flexible. Components are simply a way of conveniently dividing up the UI into discrete parts and making the app more manageable. You can just use HTML5 elements like `<nav>` and `<main>` and `<section>` in that page if you want.